# Stack, bounded stack and Liskov substitution property

Tags: stack, liskov-substitution-principle

Could a bounded stack data structure (a stack with an upper limit) be implemented as a subtype of a conventional stack without violating the Liskov substitution property?

A conventional stack could be used in place of a bounded stack, but a bounded stack may only be used in place of a conventional stack if it has a large enough limit. Am I correct with this idea?

Is the liskov property inversely true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liskov substituion princple is stated as

*Let q(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then q(y) should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.*

Let us say T is type Stack and S is a subtype of T of type BoundedStack.

Now, let us define q(x) as the capacity of stack x.

If x is an instance of T then the capacity is infinite/boundless.
If x is an instance of S then this does not hold as the capacity is now bounded.

Therefore the principle does not hold.

Comment: @monkjack: Is the capacity boundless, or is it simply ill-defined?  If the capacity is ill-defined, why wouldn't a class with defined capacity and defined behavior on overflow be substitutable for one where neither the real capacity nor the overflow behavior were specified?

Answer (score 0):

obviously bounded stack will generate a new type of exception for push method. So it does not comply LSP.

Answer (score 0):

If there were really such a thing as an unbounded stack, a bounded stack would not be a subtype of it.  On the other hand, the semantics of a "conventional" stack are probably more like "If the number of objects pushed doesn't exceed some vague, unknowable, and arbitrarily-variable limit, push the object; otherwise fail in some arbitrary and undefined fashion."  If a regular stack provides a Count property and promises that any stack whose Count is 1,000 or less will be able to accept another item, a bounded stack with a capacity of 1,000 or greater would be fully substitutable for the "conventional" one.  If it doesn't make any particular promise of capacity, a bounded stack with any capacity would be substitutable.